# Make div responsive with no text content

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I have a scenario where the container div will have lots of child div but none of the div will have actual text content. All the child div will have the width and height in **%** of the container div. Now if put the width and height of container div in **px** then it shows up in browser if i put the width & height of container too in **%** then none of the div is render in browser. just like this little snippet.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="line1 line">
        <div class="item1">
        <div class="item2">
    </div>
    <div class="line2 line">
        <div class="item1">
        <div class="item2">
    </div>
</div>
```

Css:

```
.container{
    width: 540px;
    height: 440px;
}
.line{
    margin: 5% auto;
}
.line1{
    width: 15%; 
    height: 8%;
}
.line2{
    width: 40%;
    height: 12%;
}
```

if i do

```
.container{
  width: 50%; //50% of browser screen width
  height: 60%;//60% of browser screen height
}
```

Then none of the div is rendered in browser. Any solution?

Comment: Is your page HTML or XHML? Self-closing `div` tags is not valid HTML.

Comment: How can you tell if its working or not without any borders or backgrounds? Also, probably need to set the `body` to `height:100%` as if undefined it'll assume `auto`.

Comment: what you mean by render??you mean div are now showing when inspecting with firbug are some other inspection tool???

Comment: 50% of what ? if parent has no height rules and valid valu, it will be 50% of nothing :)

Comment: @Fabrício Matté: Sorry, closing div was a mistake i have updated that.
Kashif R: Yes my mean by render is divs are not showing when i inspect them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works for me: http://jsbin.com/esosoc/1/edit

As @dominic-b-c pointed out, you might want to set `html, body { height: 100%; }`. You have everything in percentages that turn out to be relevant to body, while body has it's height measured based on the height of the content. So set the height explicitly.

Comment: Thanks. setting hight on html, body to 100% solved the problem.